# locate view class by name

Tags: ember.js

I'm aware of `Ember.View.views[someId]` to locate "instances" of Views. Is there a similar way of looking up a View "class" by string value?  I have a situation where the value of an item in a list determines which view class gets instantiated and stuffed into a container view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({ ... });

App["TestView"].create();
```

​

Comment: App.get('TestView') works also. I think it makes no difference, but perhaps just more "emberist"

Comment: Hmm, maybe, though why don't we use App.set("TestView", Ember.View.extend({ ... }))?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to switch the view class as the rendering will certainly be based on the item's state?

I would rather make the *view's template* conditional, like this:

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({

  itemBinding: 'controller.content',

  templateName: function () {
    var kind = this.get('item.kind');
    return '%@_item_view'.fmt(kind);
  }.property('item.kind')
});
```

*(Here, I aliased the item in the view for more clarity)*

You then need as much templates as you have `kind`s.
For instance: if you have `kind`'s value in `[valid, invalid]`, you would have two templates: `valid_item_view.handlebars` & `invalid_item_view.handlebars`.

Comment: Mike-thanks! In this case I had a one-of-many initial entry point situation on the first page, where each path is almost a full blown app by itself, with many sub-pages. So for conceptual clarity, I kept it as logically different and clearly named views, each with it's own template. But your suggestion would work well - thanks for showing how. In any case the design is being redone a little bit, due to the new router stuff.  Too much good stuff in Ember :=)